# Generate SDP file

Tags: android, streaming, vlc, rtp, sdp

I'm trying to stream from my android device on a local PC host. So, I use some sipvoip libraries like sipdroidsocket. The thing is that wireshark catches all the packets from my android device, but VLC can't play the data stream (Rtp) and the error popup tells that is necessary a SDP file format. I Google it and it seems like an informative file to prepare the  media player.

How to generate this file? It is generated on my android app and sent to the PC or just deployed on the PC which runs VLC?

Answer (score 0):

Sent to the PC from the RtspServer... See [RFC2326](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt) Or my Article on Codeproject [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp)